# Which encoding format .NET JSON serialised uses for Image / Binary data

Tags: ios, .net, uiimage, restkit

I am calling a RESTFul service which returns an image, this service is written in .NET, problem is I have tried base64 decoding but it didn't decode image properly and couldn't display, the service is being called in iOS client, I want to know if it uses some different encoding format.

Here is the code on my iOS app side, it uses Base64 encode / decode

```
static char encodingTable[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
static char decodingTable[128];

+ (void) initialize {
    if (self == [Base64 class]) {
        memset(decodingTable, 0, ArrayLength(decodingTable));
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < ArrayLength(encodingTable); i++) {
            decodingTable[encodingTable[i]] = i;
        }
    }
}


+ (NSString*) encode:(const uint8_t*) input length:(NSInteger) length {
    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        for (NSInteger j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }

        NSInteger index = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[index + 0] =                    encodingTable[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[index + 1] =                    encodingTable[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[index + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? encodingTable[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[index + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? encodingTable[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                  encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
}


+ (NSString*) encode:(NSData*) rawBytes {
    return [self encode:(const uint8_t*) rawBytes.bytes length:rawBytes.length];
}


+ (NSData*) decode:(const char*) string length:(NSInteger) inputLength {
    if ((string == NULL) || (inputLength % 4 != 0)) {
        return nil;
    }

    while (inputLength > 0 && string[inputLength - 1] == '=') {
        inputLength--;
    }

    NSInteger outputLength = inputLength * 3 / 4;
    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:outputLength];
    uint8_t* output = data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger inputPoint = 0;
    NSInteger outputPoint = 0;
    while (inputPoint < inputLength) {
        char i0 = string[inputPoint++];
        char i1 = string[inputPoint++];
        char i2 = inputPoint < inputLength ? string[inputPoint++] : 'A'; /* 'A' will decode to \0 */
        char i3 = inputPoint < inputLength ? string[inputPoint++] : 'A';

        output[outputPoint++] = (decodingTable[i0] << 2) | (decodingTable[i1] >> 4);
        if (outputPoint < outputLength) {
            output[outputPoint++] = ((decodingTable[i1] & 0xf) << 4) | (decodingTable[i2] >> 2);
        }
        if (outputPoint < outputLength) {
            output[outputPoint++] = ((decodingTable[i2] & 0x3) << 6) | decodingTable[i3];
        }
    }

    return data;
}


+ (NSData*) decode:(NSString*) string {
    return [self decode:[string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] length:string.length];
}
```

If you have any experience on .NET JSON serialised probably you can figure this out quickly

Comment: I'd expect it to use base64, but it's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing any of your code on either side or the sample data. Please give an example.

Comment: Are you really using RestKit? Is the image sent as base64? Not enough details...

Comment: @wain i am using RestKit on iOS side but it fails in decoding the image , the person who wrote the API has least idea about what encoding goes in , he is using .NET client to decode and it works fine there.

Comment: @wain also i receive the image in string and trying to decode using Base64 code attached

Comment: Lookout for BigEndian / LittleEndian issues, Bytes Per Pixel, Bytes Per Row?